# rails has_many through with independent through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a User model, Person model and Company model.

a User has many companies through Person and vice versa.

But i would like to be able to populate People and Companies that are not tied to Users that can be tied later.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :people
  has_many :companies, :through => :people
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :company_id
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :people
  has_many :users, :through => :person
end
```

now in the console i want to be doing the following

```
User.find(1).companies
```

then it should find me the companies in which user(1) is a person of interest.

Have I got this wrong, is there a small change that I should be making.

Comment: For one thing, you have ":through => :people" for User and ":through => :person" for Company.  That will probably make your console command work, fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Person model can't directly "belong_to" more than one, your `belongs_to :users` and `belongs_to :companies` associations won't work that way. Companies-to-people need to be connected through another join table that describes the relationship between them, for example **Employment** which points to one instance of each model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :companies, :through => :employments
end

class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :people, :through => :employments
end
```

You can then use the `:through` option to associate the many companies/people on the other side of that employment relationship in the middle.

Similarly, if a Person can be owned by more than one User then you will need a join model between those two entities as well.

Comment: person was supposed to be my join table, is kinda messed it up

Comment: Andrew, you may wish to consider revising your words, as you most certainly CAN "belong_to more than one". In fact you are doing so in your own example (in Employment). Also, since Rails is notorious for its 'automagical' approach to things, you might also consider stating that the Employment table is an _example_ of what could be used (whereas your statement currently implies it "needs" to be Employment). Again, thanks for your contribution, but just wanted to throw out a few housekeeping items, especially for "Rails/Ruby Newbies"

Answer (score 0):

Just as a followup, in a `has_many :through` relationship, there is nothing that says you cannot use your join table (in your case, **Person**) independently. By nature of the relationship, you are joining through a completely separate ActiveRecord model, which is what most notably distinguishes it from the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

As Brad pointed out in his comment, you need to pluralize 'person' to 'people' in your relationship. Other than that, it looks like you set it up correctly. Exposing `:user_id` and `:company_id` with `attr_accessible` will enable you to mass-assign these values later from a postback, but often times you want to shy away from doing so with role-based associations, as you may not want to leave them exposed to potential HTTP Post attacks.

Remember, in your controller you can always do something like this with or without `attr_accessible`:

```
@person = Person.new
@person.user = User.find(...)
@person.company = Company.find(...)
@person.save
```

Hope that helps.